# Enabling ANSI escape code processing on the modern Windows command line? [C]

Tags: c, winapi, windows-console

I've heard that modern Windows consoles support [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (COLORS), but you have to enable them.

Using the 19042.746 build of Windows 10, it should just be a simple affair of enabling it using the [SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING); // from windows.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but after setting it, it still doesn't support ANSI escape colors. What am I missing?

Real life examples

```c
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleMode(hConsole, ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING);
printf("\033[32mThis is green");
```

Prints out

```
[31mThis is green
```

Sources:

- *[SetConsoleMode function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode)*
- *[Bash tips: Colors and formatting (ANSI/VT100 Control sequences)](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)*

Comment: There is an example on a page linked to that document: [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). One point is that you should preserve existing modes by using `|` rather than over-writing the mode.

Comment: Your output does not match your source. Please [edit] your question and provide a [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT`. You need to use GetConsoleMode first to get the current mode (it usually contains `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT`), and then add `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` to the mode:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD mode = 0;
GetConsoleMode(hConsole, &mode); //
SetConsoleMode(hConsole, mode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING);
printf("\033[32mThis is green");
```

Result:

[image]